# Python Pandas ( сохранение данных )

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, pandas, csv

Появилась такая проблема: есть данные в `pandas.DataFrame`, как их сохранить в файл, чтобы они не "потеряли вид" как в `DataFrame`.

**Надо, чтобы получилось так, только в Excele**

[image: pandas.DataFrame]

**С моим кодом получается так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd


with open('text.txt') as file:
    words1 = str(file.read()).split()
    words1 = dict(Counter(words1).most_common())

word_dict = {
     'Слова': list(words1),
    'Количество': list(words1.values())
}

x = pd.DataFrame(word_dict, index=range(len(words1)))
print(x)

with open('info.csv', 'w') as f_csv:
    x.to_csv(f_csv)
```

Comment: Используйте соответствующий метод: [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel).

Comment: Вы неправильно открыли ваш `.csv` файл в Excel. Смотрите [здесь](https://office-guru.ru/excel/preobrazovyvaem-csv-v-excel-kak-importirovat-faily-csv-v-elektronnye-tablicy-excel-368.html) как это сделать правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии к вашему вопросу, ваш CSV файл (почти) в порядке, только вы его открыли в Excel непригодным способом.

(Вы можете проверить ваш `.csv` файл тоже например на сайте [Online CSV Editor and Viewer](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-viewer-editor.htm).)

Вы делаете это слишком сложно. Здесь упрощенная версия вашей программы с какими-то добавками:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd


with open('text.txt') as file:
    words1 = file.read().split()

words1 = Counter(words1).most_common()

x = pd.DataFrame(words1, columns=['Слова', 'Количество'])
print(x)

x.to_csv(f_csv, index=True)
```

---

*Объяснения:*

Команду

```
words1 = str(file.read()).split()
```

я упростил на

```
words1 = file.read().split()
```

т. к. `file.read()` уже является строкой.

---

Часть

```
word_dict = {
     'Слова': list(words1),
    'Количество': list(words1.values())
}
```

я просто удалил; вместо `word_dict` я в конструкторе `pd.DataFrame()` использовал прямо список парей `words1` (т.к. метод `.most_common()` возвращает список парей `(слово, частота)`), и имена столбцов `'Слова'` и `'Количество'` использовал прямо в нем.

---

Вместо

```
x = pd.DataFrame(word_dict, index=range(len(words1)))
```

я использовал

```
x = pd.DataFrame(words1, columns=['Слова', 'Количество'])
```

потому что индекс будет стандартно таким, как вы хотели, но я добавил имя столбцов.

---

Вместо вашего

```
with open('info.csv', 'w') as f_csv:
    x.to_csv(f_csv)
```

я использовал просто

```
x.to_csv('info.csv', index=True)        # вы хотите сохранить тоже index
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.to_excel(result_file, index=False)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой ответ, чтобы он был более развёрнутым и понятным для автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Самый постой и быстрый способ сохранять DataFrame - это использовать его родной формат pickle:

```py
yourDataFrame.to_pickle("yourDataFrameFile.pkl")  # Save DataFrame to pickle file
yourDataFrame = read_pickle("yourDataFrameFile.pkl")  # Load DataFrame from pickle file
```

Comment: в вопросе речь была об использовании сохранённого файла в программе ms/excel. то, что вы предлагаете, можно будет так использовать?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Нет, программа Excel не сможет открыть файл формата .pkl.
Если нужно выгрузить  panda'вский DataFrame в формат Excel, то сама pandas предлагают для этого метод  pandas.DataFrame.to_excel (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html )

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь `XlsxWriter`.

```bash
pip install XlsxWriter
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# ...
# ...
# ...

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, 'Data', index=False)

writer.close()
```